# TeamCity config transform error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, build, teamcity

I'm trying to switch out a web config file using team city so that each deployment has the correct settings.

I've added an AfterBuild target in my .csproj file

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Delete Files="$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName).config" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)\Config\Web.$(Configuration).config" DestinationFiles="$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName).config" />
  </Target>
```

and then called this in team city in the "Targets" section of a visual studio solutions runner.

I keep getting this error when the team city build happens:

"error MSB4057: The target "AfterBuild" does not exist in the project."

Does anyone know why I might be getting this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Whilst I may not be able to answer your question directly, I can provide an alternative solution to execute a config transformation during the build process if it helps.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions, I'm a bit tight on time though so looking for a simple option ideally

Comment: I suspect you're getting the error because the solution (sln) doesn't contain the target, the csproj does.  However, if you've added the AfterBuild target to the csproj you shouldn't have to directly run the target in order for it to run; MsBuild should automatically hook into it.  Have you tried it without the target specified in the build step?

Comment: @SteveChapman Thanks, i removed the target from team city and made a couple of changes to the msbuild command and managed to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel free to use this powershell build step to help with config transformations

**1. Create a PowerShell script and add it to version control**

Use the following script - [xdt-config-transform.ps1](https://gist.github.com/software-programmer/7781104d29ce6e50fdc3da4a12964869)

**2. Add Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll to your version control in the same location as the PowerShell script. This file should be on your local disk if you have Visual Studio installed**

**3. Create a PowerShell build step to do the transformation**

[image: Build Step]

**4. Pass in the parameters to the script**

[image]

**5. Define the values for the parameters**

This is the path to the config file you wish to transform
[image: Config File]

This is the path to the config file that holds the transformations
[image: Config Transform File]

This is the path to the Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll file
[image: Library File]

The additional parameters support a simple find and replace functionality that we needed at some point, but you could strip this out.

Hope this helps